# Alert dialog box before exit the inappbrowser in Cordova

Tags: cordova, alert, inappbrowser

May i know how to create a alert dialog box to ask user whether they confirm to quit the inappbrowser in cordova when user press the hardware back button? I had try using ref.addEventListener('exit', onBackKeyDown); to do it but not successful. Please help me and provide any solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

use **"_blank"** instead of **"_self"**. The 'exit' event won't fire if external source opened in the existing view.

```
var ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=no');

     ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event){  Exit(); });

 function Exit(){
              navigator.notification.confirm(
                'Do you want to exit app?',  
                function(i){
                    if(i==2)
                     {
                       navigator.app.exitApp(); //This will Close the App
                     }
                },              
                'App Name',            
                'Cancel,Exit'          
              );
 }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I want to have the dialog box before exit the google. I just try your code... The dialog come out after exit the google website.

Answer (score 0):

To create a alert dialog box to ask user whether they confirm to quit the inappbrowser in cordova when user press the hardware back button, you need to:

A) Modify InAppBrowserDialog.java located at your_project/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/inappbrowser/. 
B) Add import android.content.DialogInterface; to add the required imports. 
C) Modify the onBackPressed() function
FROM:

```
public void onBackPressed () {
if (this.inAppBrowser == null) {
    this.dismiss();
} else {
    // better to go through the in inAppBrowser
    // because it does a clean up
    if (this.inAppBrowser.hardwareBack() && this.inAppBrowser.canGoBack()) {
        this.inAppBrowser.goBack();
    }  else {
        this.inAppBrowser.closeDialog();
    }
}
```

}

TO:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("Exit")
    .setMessage("You are about to exit, are you sure?")
    .setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            if (inAppBrowser == null) {
                dismiss();
            } 
            else {
                // better to go through the in inAppBrowser
                // because it does a clean up
                if (inAppBrowser.hardwareBack() && inAppBrowser.canGoBack()) {
                    inAppBrowser.goBack();
                }  else {
                    inAppBrowser.closeDialog();
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To show the popup confirmation after clicking back button.

First of all install the dialogs plugin by running 'cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs'.

Then install cordova-plugin-injectview by running 'cordova plugin add https://github.com/lesteenman/cordova-plugin-injectview.git'

Add bellow code in your page which is loaded by the inAppBrowser.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit ?", onConfirm, "Confirmation", "Yes,No");
}
function onConfirm(button) {
    if(button==1){
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```